# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20, 1 20, 2016 10:28 am" (at offset 0)

Tags: java, android, date, parseexception

I am working on android application in which i want to parse my date according to my format. But i am getting Unparseable date exception on it. My code is given below, please help me out to parse my date according to my format.

```
        SimpleDateFormat stestRequest = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aa");
         try { 
            month = month +1;
Date  dateRequestSelected      = stestRequest.parse(day+", "+month+" "+day+", "+year+" "+hour+":"+minutes+ state); // 20, 1 20, 2016 10:28 am
    // I need a format like Monday, January 20, 2016 10:28 am
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Please help me out here.

Comment: you don't have comma b/w 1 and 20

Comment: If you already *have* the values separately, why are you converting them into text and parsing them at all? Just set the relevant parts in a `Calendar`, e.g. with [`Calendar.set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set-int-int-int-int-int-int-)

Answer (score 2):

`EEE` stays for day in the week (TEXT), but you have the day of the month (number). You have to use `d` instead of `EEE`. The same applies to `MMM` which should be `M`.

```
SimpleDateFormat stestRequest = new SimpleDateFormat("d, M dd, yyyy hh:mm aa");
```

You can read more about it here  [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer here. It is still not displaying in date format which i want. It is displaying it like Wed Jan 20 12:14:00 GMT+04:00 2016. I need to display it like Wednesday January 20 12:40:00 am 2016